# Using $.get to print page Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to print the elements of a page using this code:

```
$('#some_button').click(function(){
    var url = window.location.href;
    var contents = $.get(url);
    alert(contents.responseText);
});
```

but this returns a blank string, and trying to print `contents.status` gives me the error:

```
Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11
```

This code works just fine from the browser console so it would seem this is a load state issue.  But because this is in a click listener I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.get` is asynchronous by default, so use it like this:

```
$('#some_button').click(function(){
    var url = window.location.href;
    $.get(url, function(r){
        alert(r);
    });
});
```

If you want to use it synchronously, then use `async : false` in the parameters:

```
var contents = $.get(url, {
    async : false
});
```

Note that that will seize up the browser, though.

Comment: yep, that works.  But r is itself the page contents, so you don't need `responseText`.